# Constructor for array of unknown size of stl lists in a Hashtable

Tags: c++, arrays, stl, hashtable

I am attempting to create a templated hash table to store pointers to objects. These objects are derived from a base class `Sequence` that 3 classes are derived from `DNA` `RNA` `AA`. My main problem is, I'm not sure how to set up the constructor for my hash table class. I already have my hash function and key method defined, but i can't test them. My trouble spot is, the number of buckets for my hash table aren't known beforehand. It is read in from a file, so the size of my array is not known when the object is instantiated. The hash table uses separate chaining to resolve collisions,thus the `std::list`. I've declared my list as a private member of my class`HashTable`.

```
std::list<T> *table;
```

I know my lists have to be dynamically allocated. Something along the lines of

```
HashTable<T>(){
    table = new std::list<T>;   
}
```

This is a homework assignment and we have to use an array of lists, instead of a vector, as the array should be constant size. I've tried and researched for hours, and am still not sure how to do this. My hash table object is declared as a private member of another class `SequenceDatabase` that reads in the file and handles the data accordingly.

```
HashTable<Sequence*> hash;
```

I've also declared the hash object in the class constructor

```
SequenceDatabase::SequenceDatabase(){
HashTable<Sequence*> hash; 
}
```

Short snippet of `SequenceDatabase` to show how I'm setting it up.

```
// function reads in the filename creates a data stream
void SequenceDatabase::importEntries(std::string inputFile){
std::ifstream dnaFile(inputFile);
char command;                           // ***************
std::string label, sequence, type;      // local variables
int buckets, id, length, index, orf;    // ***************
dnaFile >> buckets;
while(dnaFile >> command){
    Sequence* s;
    // if the command = D this allocates memory for a dna object and adds it to the hash table
    if(command == 'D'){
        dnaFile >> label >> id >> sequence >> length >> index;
        std::cout << "Adding " << label << " ...\n\n";
        s = new DNA(label, id, sequence, length, index);
```

My main questions are, do I have to create a public method in `HashTable`to set the size of the array in `SequenceDatabase`? Can i use such a method in the`HashTable` constructor. How would i go about doing this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using a pointer to a list instead of a vector of lists?

Comment: You want `table = new std::list<T>[num_buckets];`, or better yet in the initialiser list ala `HashTable() : table(new std::list<T>[num_buckets]) { ... }`.  What is `SequenceDatabase::SequenceDatabase() { HashTable<Sequence*> hash; 
}` supposed to do?  That's a temporary that's destroyed when the constructor returns; make it a member variable.

Comment: You haven't declared *the* hash object in the constructor, you have declared another completely different object with the same name.

Comment: @TonyD That is the file that the data is read in from. The number of buckets are read in from the file also, and aren't known ahead of time.

Comment: @molbdnilo That is the constructor for a separate class. This is made artificially hard by my professor. The hashtable should store pointers to objects that have a getKey() method which is a public method of the Sequence class.